# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `ic`.`livros`(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") id`))

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

Id like to create de table "livros" with de foreign key "users_id", from the table "users", but i cannot migrate.

**TABLE:**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('livros', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
 
            $table->integer('users_id');
            $table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            /*Auth::user()->id;*/

            $table->text('namel');
            $table->string('autor');
            $table->string('editora');
            $table->string('categoria');
            $table->string('classificação');
            $table->text('descricao');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();


        });
    }
```

Comment: Change this to `$table->unsignedBigInteger('users_id');`

Comment: The column definition for users_id on livros and id on users must match. By default in Laravel 8, the column definition for primary keys is unsignedBigInteger, so use that for users_id.

Comment: Please show us the users table migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreign key need to be same type of your parent key, your parent key from `users` table `$table->id();` is a **unsigned big integer**, so make your foreign key also the same type, change :

```php
$table->integer('users_id');
$table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

to

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger('users_id');
$table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Or, use [foreignId](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

```php
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
```